# Override CSS Style when implement Google custom search

Tags: css

When I implement Google Custom Search on my site, there is an extra white space which I want to get rid of. Here is Google's official example: http://googlecustomsearch.appspot.com/elementv2/two-column_v2.html

Use Chrome "Inspect", if you hover your mouse over the following code, the blank line will be highlighted. (don't do any searches). Is it possible to hide this blank line?

```
<div id="___gcse_1">...</div>
```

This seems to be produced by code in http://googlecustomsearch.appspot.com/elementv2/two-column_v2.html

```
.cse .gsc-control-cse,
.gsc-control-cse {
  padding: 1em;
  width: auto;
}
```

I added the following code in my css file, but it didn't change anything.

```
.cse .gsc-control-cse,
.gsc-control-cse {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Edited to add a screenshot: the white space is only visible with the inspect tool because of the white background.

[image]

Comment: Check when each stylesheet is loaded and look into [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Which space you were talking about please explain with the help of images

Comment: Thanks, Marc. !important seems to be the right solution, I'm seeing changes how. Cheers!

Comment: @lastsmoke Though you should always resort to `!important` as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc Hjorth, I was able to override outside css style with the keyword **!important**.